# Biometric Authentication in iOS without LocalAuthentication

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, face-id

I'm trying out biometric authentication in an iOS app. I was wondering if there is any framework or library other than Apple's own LocalAuthentication?

This question is just for a R&D purpose

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id